# Getting error "Cannot read property 'template' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've upgraded my ember version to 1.9.1 and handlebar version to 2.0.0. My templates got compiled successfully.

After compilation, in templates.js file am getting something like,

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["application"] = Ember.HTMLBars.template({"compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data)`
```

Is the error due to "Ember.HTMLBars.template", instead it should be compiled like "Ember.Handlebars.template" or some other reason?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have mixed versions.

`Ember.HTMLBars` is a feature of Ember 1.10 and older.

Use the https://github.com/components/ember/releases repo to pick all files belonging to the same release.

Ember 1.9.1 is very, very old.

Consider migrating your legacy app to a modern [Ember CLI](http://ember-cli.com) setup.

Use the opposite approach: instead of trying to upgrade your legacy app, try creating a new one from scratch by carefully moving the functionality from the old app piece by piece, making sure to use modern Ember techniques.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changed templateNamespace and it's perfectly working now. :)

Comment: Consider filing an answer to your own question.